# Using Wilcoxon and Cliff's delta for comparing two sets of monitored variables?

Tags: python, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I want to compare the following example vectors:

```
a: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b: [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

`a[i]` represents a monitored variable `i` during execution `a` (likewise for `b`)

The things I would like to find out are:

1. Are the pairs significantly different?
2. How different are they?
3. Which ones are different from each other (pairwise comparisons)?

For (1) and (2) I am thinking about the Wilcoxon signed rank test and Cliff's delta effect size measurement. (3) can be done using simple programming.

So, my questions are:

1. Are these the right test and method for this problem?
2. When I perform Wilcoxon in Python for vectors `a` and `b`, I get `(5.0, 1.0)` as output. I do not understand the p-value of 1.0 as I consider the sets to be very different. Also, what is the 5.0 value? Is it the W value? When I manually calculate this, I get 0.0....

**Edit**

To clarify what 'different' means to me:
I am working on a method to compare usage profiles monitored during test execution of software. So, an example profile may be a:

```
a: [func1 = 0sec, func2 = 1sec, func3 = 2sec, func4 = 3sec, func5 = 4sec]
b: [func1 = 0sec, func2 = 3sec, func3 = 2sec, func4 = 3sec, func5 = 4sec]
```

with sec being total seconds execution time in that function during run a or b of a specific test, but with b ran on (slightly) changed code (= a new version).

I would like to compare this profile to another profile to verify whether execution time has changed significantly.

From the answers I understand that it is difficult to say something about significance for only two executions. Would it be better if I have 10 executions of a and 10 of b, calculate mean and stdev for all functions and compare those using Wilcoxon?

Comment: It comes down to what you mean by "different." It is evident that your (unstated) concept of difference is not that of the Wilcoxon test, which sees a perfectly symmetrical multiset of differences between components of these vectors: $\{4,2,0,-2,-4\}$, with equal amounts of positive and negative values. These two vectors are as *like* as possible from the Wilcoxon point of view, because *it does not care about the order of the data.* So, to get answers to your critical question--what is the "right" test--you first need to edit your post to state what *kinds* of differences you wish to detect.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood - I thought that the Wilcoxon does care about the order of the data. I am not sure what my concept of difference is, I was hoping Wilcoxon would give me a 'metric' to express difference between the sets.

Comment: Re the edit: Your data are *multivariate*; there is one variable per test. Your two vectors are each samples of *one* observation of this multivariate process. Although it's not impossible to establish whether two such vectors are "significantly" different, in practice the answer is almost worthless. You need to obtain several vectors representing "a" and several representing "b" so that you can assess their variability. Almost all statistical tests proceed by comparing some measure of difference to the amount of variability. Can you, then, replicate your tests in order to obtain such data?

Comment: I tried to rephrase better... does this help?

Comment: I can't see that your rephrase addresses the key points. You can collapse your profiles to total execution times to get two values to compare. But if you wish to compare profiles component by component that's a multivariate problem. Also, if you think that data should be summarized by means and standard deviations Wilcoxon isn't suitable at all, but you should be addressing whether a t test applies.

Comment: OK, I will have a look at multivariate methods. Thanks. If you have any pointers on which methods would be interesting that would be excellent :)